# Check Entire Website's Links

Tags: html, link-checking

I know similar questions have been asked, but I'm not sure about the answers (and I can't easily test all of them), so before I go crazy continuing to search, I want to ask: Is there an easy way to crawl all the pages on a website and check them for broken and invalid links automatically?  Prefereably I'd like a solution that does not require an install or compile as I'm severely limited.  Thanks.

Comment: Any solution will require you to either install something or compile something. Are you looking for the magic link checker pixies?

Comment: Pretty much.  I'm hoping there's a good program that I can just download and run, without having to run an installer first.

Comment: Would a web app satisfy your "no-install" requirement?

Comment: @ScottGrodberg At this point, no.  I don't even work at that company anymore.  But I had gotten the task done, and the entire site started (and still is) running much smoother than it had previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Xenu's Link Sleuth. It does require an install, but is light-weight and no compile is needed.

http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html

Comment: I looked at that, but it's still got an installer application.

Comment: Well yeah, but you can easily install it somewhere and then just zip the program folder. Here, I just did that: http://www.2shared.com/fadmin/15876502/98e6a26b/Xenu.zip.html

Comment: @gablin  I'm blocked from most installations, but the zip helped.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of Xenu's Link Sleuth :-) In the old days, it didn't have an install because this wasn't a priority for me. More and more people complained and one of them pointed me to a tool, so it's with an installer now, first it was InnoSetup, now it's NSIS.

"gablin" is correct, the .EXE file can be transferred. Nevertheless, I'd warn you against starting an "external" software within a "nasty" company. Rather, try to beg your way through the internal bureaucracy.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear why you are avoiding installers.  I would suggest installing at home, try copying to a thumb drive, then run on a thumb drive.

This may require that you install one or more virtual machines.

Comment: At the time, I was working under severe restrictions on what could and could not be run on company computers.  Anything with an installer had to go through a rather severe vetting process, but it was much simpler to see a non-installer utility start, run, and what it was doing (don't ask me why, I never understood).